# Is there any way to represent the range 0x80-0xFF as a single byte in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

I have been fighting with this for a while, I'm trying to calculate a checksum for a byte[] as the 1s complement of the 1s complement sum of 16 bit words in the array.  The sum is fairly easy (though I'm sure I could be more efficient) but when I flip the bits and get a 'negative' value it sign extends to 4 bytes.  performing bitwise and with 0xff gives me the proper value, but because I'm trying to include the checksum in another byte array I need it as a byte.  Casting back to a byte gives me the 4 byte int again.  Bizarrely, I can store this (4 byte) value in a byte array and print it without causing issues.  Is there any way to force Java to leave me with just one single byte with a negative sign bit?  In this particular example the bytes are 0xef and 0xfd.

My code for calculating the checksum is:

```
public byte[] checksum (byte[] b) {
    byte[] check = new byte[3] ;
    check[1] += b[0];
    check[2] += b[1];
    check[1] += b[2];
    check[2] += b[3];
    check[1] += b[4];
    check[2] += b[5];
    check[1] += b[6];
    check[2] += b[7];
    check[1] += b[8];
    check[2] += b[9];
    check[1] += b[10];
    check[2] += b[11];
    check[1] += b[12];
    check[2] += b[13];
    check[1] += b[14];
    check[2] += b[15];
    check[1] += b[16];
    check[2] += b[17];
    check[1] += b[18];
    check[2] += b[19];

    check[2] += check[0] ;

    byte[] ret = new byte[2] ;
    ret[0] = (byte)~check[1];
    ret[1] = (byte)~check[2];

    return ret ;
}
```

Again to be clear, this gives me a byte[] with size 2, where each element seems to be 4 bytes.

Printing the returned array with

```
byte[] r = checksum (b);
for (int i = 0; i < r.length; ++ i) {
        System.out.println (String.format("0x%2s", Integer.toHexString(r[i])).replace(' ', '0')) ;
    }
```

displays

```
0xffffffef
0xfffffffd
```

How is that even possible, and how can I avoid it?  If it's just a display issue that's fine, but it looks like each element of my returned array is actually 4 bytes.

Comment: *"Again to be clear, this gives me a byte[] with size 2, where each element is 4 bytes."* No, it doesn't. It's a `byte[2]`. Whatever output you're seeing that suggests it is, is misleading you. :-)

Comment: *Casting back to a byte gives me the 4 byte int again.* This doesn't make sense. Please explain how you came to that conclusion.

Comment: What's the point of `check[2] += check[0] ;` when you've never assigned a value to `check[0]` (and so it's `0`)? Indeed, why is `check` `byte[3]` at all, rather than `byte[2]`?

Comment: Most of the issue is just that when you go from byte to int, if you want it to be treated unsigned, you have to do `& 0xFF`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem isn't in your byte array, it's in how you're printing it. `Integer.toHexString()` expects an `int`. When you pass a `byte` as `int`, an automatic *widening conversion* is performed, which includes *sign extension*. You can undo the effects of sign extension like this:

```
Integer.toHexString(r[i] & 0xFF)
```

Comment: I feel pretty dumb for banging my head against this for so many hours... thanks for the help.